# Relation between weak derivative and partial derivative.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Is there some kind of relation between weak derivative and partial derivative. I have been reading weak derivative as the weakening the partial derivative. But I found it rather difficult to conceptualise the weak derivative as a derivative . 
Any help would be great . 
Thanks

Comment: Integration by parts is the link between weak derivatives and actual derivatives. The wikipedia article has a pretty nice exposition on it.

Comment: As you can read [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space#Motivation), there are also weak partial derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say anything about context here, so let's try it with distributions. I'll stick with one variable for simplicity. So let $T$ be a distribution, and $\varphi$ a test function (i.e., smooth with compact support). Write $\varphi_h(x)=\varphi(x-h)$, and $\langle T_h,\varphi\rangle=\langle T,\varphi_{-h}\rangle$. Then by definition
$$
  \langle T',\varphi\rangle
  =-\langle T,\varphi'\rangle
  =\Bigl\langle T,\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\varphi_h-\varphi}{h}\Bigr\rangle
  =\lim_{h\to0}\Bigl\langle\frac{T_{-h}-T}{h},\varphi\Bigr\rangle,
$$
so that $T'$ is the weak limit of $$\frac{T_{-h}-T}{h}$$ as $h\to0$. As part of the calculation, you need to know that $$\varphi'=-\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\varphi_h-\varphi}{h}$$ in the topology of the space of test functions.

The signs are a bit awkward here, but I try to stick with the common sign convention for function translation. If $T$ were a function, of course $$\frac{T_{-h}-T}{h}(x)=\frac{T(x+h)-T(x)}{h}$$ as expected, and then you get to take the weak (distributional)limit of that.

Comment: Is there a reason you write $\phi' = - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi_h - \phi}{h}$ and not $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi - \phi_h}{h}$?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik No *important* reason, just the fact that the quotient $\frac{\varphi_h-\varphi}{h}$ appeared higher up. (Aside TeXnichal remark: Whereas `\phi` produces $\phi$, `\varphi` produces the variant form $\varphi$ that I used.)